# Trim image-border connected white regions

Tags: image-processing

I have this image:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtmAK.png"]:
```

[image]

What is an elegant way to **automatically** trim the border-connected white regions leaving the colored region?

## desired output:

[image]

Binarized outputs accepted also.

## attempt 1:

```
{x, y} = ImageDimensions[im];
out1 = DeleteBorderComponents[Binarize[im] ];
centroidY = Mean[ImageKeypoints[out1]][[2]];
ImageTrim[im, {{0, centroidY - x/2}, {x, centroidY + x/2}}]
```

[image]

## Background:

This method has to work automatically for images with colored numbers at different y-positions.

Here are some examples:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ImageTrim?

Comment: Yes, But I am looking for an automatic way to do it.

Comment: something in the spirit of `DeleteBorderComponents`

Comment: Does `ImageCrop` work?

Comment: I am looking for an elegant automatic method that may involve `ImageTrim` and `ImageCrop`. See `attempt 1` in the question. I way to perform this operation on 500k such images with numbers at different heights.

Comment: `ImageCrop[img]` works fine on your one copyable example. Does anything go wrong with the other examples?

Comment: @CarlWoll Your right! I didn't realize `ImageCrop` could do that! I thought I had to specify parameters. Nice solution!